# send a variable from a perl script into a command line

Tags: perl, cmd

I have a perl script that always returns yesterday's date and the date is stored on a variable called `$yesterday`

Now, I am running that perl script using cmd prompt. After it figures out what yesterday's date was I would like to pass $yesterday somehow into the cmd line so that it can open up a "$yesterday.txt" file. The txt files are already there and match the date format in the filename.

Comment: Are you asking how to [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a file?

Comment: If you're using Linux, you can use GNU `date` program to generate a date on the command line. For example, `date -d "-1 days" +%Y-%m-%d` to generates yesterday's date in YYYY-MM-DD form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a file?

```
my $file = "$yesterday.txt";
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open $file for reading: $!";
```

See the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for more information on the `open` command.

Comment: Well, there you go then. Perhaps you should check the permissions on the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply include the $variable in the string of the command or use string concatenation to put the static and variable parts together:

```
system("echo yesterday >$yesterday.txt");
```

or

```
system("echo yesterday >" . $yesterday . ".txt");
```

The above calls a commandline program or command from perl and the command includes the value of your $yesterday variable.

Comment: I get an "access denied" error if I try to access the .txt file using the System() method. However, I can still access the text file using command prompt manually.